# NSPredicate for regex pattern matching crashes

Tags: ios, regex, swift, nspredicate

This code:

```
 internal let emailRegex:String = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,5}"

 let emailText = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES \(emailRegex)")

 return emailText .evaluateWithObject(email)
```

Crashes with error:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format
>   string "SELF MATCHES [A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+[A-Za-z0-9.-]+.[A-Za-z]{2,5}"'

Comment: Some good reading on email validation, it may not help you solve your problem but it can help you avoid others down the line: [I Knew How To Validate An Email Address Until I Read The RFC](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides, your's I have another email regex which you can go for.

```
func isValidEmail() -> Bool {

    let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$",
                options: [.CaseInsensitive])

    return regex.firstMatchInString(self, options:[],
        range: NSMakeRange(0, emailString.characters.count)) != nil
}
```

Please check this regex.

Comment: can you please explain what is utf16.count?

Comment: thanx it works by changing utf16.count to email.characters.count

Comment: @Sohil R. Memon will explain me what 'try!' means in 'let regex =' statement.

Answer (score 3):

### This is a great way to natively handle email validation:

[Handling email validation using built-in functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41888051/887210)

### I also have this way to handle it with regex:

Here's the regex from [I Knew How To Validate An Email Address Until I Read The RFC](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/)

```
import Foundation

let pattern = "^(?!\\.)(\"([^\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\[\"\\r\\\\])*\"|([-a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~]|(?<!\\.)\\.)*)(?<!\\.)@[a-z0-9][\\w\\.-]*[a-z0-9]\\.[a-z][a-z\\.]*[a-z]$"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", pattern)

// tests in the format (email, isValid)
let tests = [
  ("NotAnEmail", false),
  ("@NotAnEmail", false),
  ("\"test\\\rblah\"@example.com", true),
  ("\"test\rblah\"@example.com", false),
  ("\"test\\\"blah\"@example.com", true),
  ("\"test\"blah\"@example.com", false),
  ("customer/department@example.com", true),
  ("$A12345@example.com", true),
  ("!def!xyz%abc@example.com", true),
  ("_Yosemite.Sam@example.com", true),
  ("~@example.com", true),
  (".wooly@example.com", false),
  ("wo..oly@example.com", false),
  ("pootietang.@example.com", false),
  (".@example.com", false),
  ("\"Austin@Powers\"@example.com", true),
  ("Ima.Fool@example.com", true),
  ("\"Ima.Fool\"@example.com", true),
  ("\"Ima Fool\"@example.com", true),
  ("Ima Fool@example.com", false)]

for (index,(email,isValid)) in tests.enumerate() {
  let eval = predicate.evaluateWithObject(email)
  if eval == isValid {
    print(index, ": VALID!")
  }
}
```

output:

```
0 : VALID!
1 : VALID!
2 : VALID!
3 : VALID!
4 : VALID!
5 : VALID!
6 : VALID!
8 : VALID!
10 : VALID!
11 : VALID!
12 : VALID!
13 : VALID!
14 : VALID!
15 : VALID!
17 : VALID!
18 : VALID!
19 : VALID!
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to use NSPredicate is

```swift
import Foundation

let emailAddress = "mailbox@example.com"
let pattern = "^.+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*$"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", argumentArray: [pattern])
let isValidEmailAddress = predicate.evaluate(with: emailAddress)
print(isValidEmailAddress)
```

The choice of an address validation method is a completely different story though.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution of the problem by

```
func isValidEmail(email:String) -> Bool
{


    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$",
        options: [.CaseInsensitive])

    return regex.firstMatchInString(email, options:[],
        range: NSMakeRange(0, email.characters.count)) != nil


}
```