# Email Validation is wrong as per Regex

Tags: ios, regex, swift, email-validation

I am using email validation into my project which method is like below

```
//MARK: isValidEmailID
    func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {
        print("validate emilId: \(testStr)")
        let emailRegEx = "^(?:(?:(?:(?: )*(?:(?:(?:\\t| )*\\r\\n)?(?:\\t| )+))+(?: )*)|(?: )+)?(?:(?:(?:[-A-Za-z0-9!#$%&’*+/=?^_'{|}~]+(?:\\.[-A-Za-z0-9!#$%&’*+/=?^_'{|}~]+)*)|(?:\"(?:(?:(?:(?: )*(?:(?:[!#-Z^-~]|\\[|\\])|(?:\\\\(?:\\t|[ -~]))))+(?: )*)|(?: )+)\"))(?:@)(?:(?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[-A-Za-z0-9]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])?)(?:\\.[A-Za-z0-9](?:[-A-Za-z0-9]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])?)*)|(?:\\[(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9]|(?:[1-9][0-9])|(?:1[0-9][0-9])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:25[0-5]))\\.){3}(?:[0-9]|(?:[1-9][0-9])|(?:1[0-9][0-9])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:25[0-5]))))|(?:(?:(?: )*[!-Z^-~])*(?: )*)|(?:[Vv][0-9A-Fa-f]+\\.[-A-Za-z0-9._~!$&'()*+,;=:]+))\\])))(?:(?:(?:(?: )*(?:(?:(?:\\t| )*\\r\\n)?(?:\\t| )+))+(?: )*)|(?: )+)?$"
        let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
        let result = emailTest.evaluateWithObject(testStr)
        return result
    }
```

**OR**

```
func isValidEmailID(email: String) -> Bool {
        let regExPattern: String = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}"
        let emailValidator: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", regExPattern)
        let isValid: Bool = emailValidator.evaluateWithObject(email)
        return isValid
    }
```

This both Regex works fine when I enter "modijecky@gmail.com" or any other wrong input but it will not work when I enter "modijecky@gmail.com.com".

So,I find out that "name@.com.com" is a valid email address and there are more sub-domains like this. So now I want user not to enter sub-domains. Is there any REGEX that validate email address within just one domain like "name@gmail.com" not with multiple domains or sub-domains.

I also try different Regex from google and implement it into project but same problem occurs. 
Please help me with it.
Thank you

Comment: Why `modijecky@gmail.com.com` is supposed wrong? `com.com` is a valid domain as well as `gmail.com.com`. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples

Comment: The only secure way to validate emails is to send an email and wait for return.

Comment: Please check my updated answer

Answer (score 6):

Don’t reinvent the wheel:

[Not Reinventing the Wheel: Email Validation in Swift](http://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2016/11/02/email-validation-swift/)

Basically you can use [`NSDataDetector`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdatadetector) to do the heavy lifting and have everything consistent and updated to the way it works in macOS and iOS natively. Not only that but you also avoid regex headaches.

```
// Simplifying the example from the website a bit

import Foundation

func validate(_ text: String) -> Bool {
  let types = NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue
  guard
    let dataDetector = try? NSDataDetector(types: types),
    let match = dataDetector
      .matches(in: text, options: [], range: NSRangeFromString(text))
      .first,
    let absoluteString = match.url?.absoluteString
    else { return false }
  return absoluteString == "mailto:\(text)"
}

validate("test@gmail.com")  // -> true
validate(" test@gmail.com") // -> false
```

This will make sure that the entire text is a single, valid email address without any superfluous characters.

Comment: Does this validate the mail id internally?

Comment: I haven’t run it through test cases exhaustively but it seems to catch most common bad addresses.

Comment: I will also use it instead of regex seems less prone to error and clean thanks for sharing. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Function Call:**

```
let result = isValidEmail(testStr: "test@test.com.op")
        if (result)
        {
            print ("passed")
        }
        else{
            print ("failed")
        }
```

**Function Definition:**

```
func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {
        // print("validate calendar: \(testStr)")
        var returnValue : Bool = false
        let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}"
        let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
        if (emailTest.evaluate(with: testStr))
        {
            let fullNameArr = testStr.components(separatedBy: "@")
            let IdName    = fullNameArr[0]
            let domainName = fullNameArr[1]
            var number = 0
            let string = domainName
            for character in domainName.characters {
                if character == "."
                {
                    number = number + 1
                }
            }
            if number <= 1
            {
                returnValue = true
            }
        }
        return returnValue
    }
```

**Result:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Same issue, It will return true when I type "name@gmail.com.com". Sorry mate but its not working

Comment: I told in my question that I dont want subdomains, I want to do it like with only one domain like 'name@gmail.com' not with sub-domain like 'name@gmail.com.com'

Comment: yeah, mate I dont want .com.com ,I only want one .com

Comment: not characters,  I mean there is domains like .com, .edu, .fr, .in etc, but only one domain not two domains. There will be many characters in domains but just one

Answer (score 0):

you should have this code to don't allow subdomain.

```
    func isValidEmail(email:String) -> Bool {

    if email.range(of: "@") == nil || email.range(of: ".") == nil{
        return false
    }

    let accountName = email.substring(to: email.range(of: "@")!.lowerBound)

    let domainName = email.substring(from: email.range(of: "@")!.upperBound)

    let subDomain = domainName.substring(from: email.range(of: ".")!.lowerBound)



    //filter for user name
    let unWantedInUName = " ~!@#$^&*()={}[]|;’:\"<>,?/`";
    //filter for domain
    let unWantedInDomain = " ~!@#$%^&*()={}[]|;’:\"<>,+?/`";
    //filter for subdomain
    let unWantedInSub = " `~!@#$%^&*()={}[]:\";’<>,?/1234567890";

    //subdomain should not be less that 2 and not greater 6
    if(!(subDomain.characters.count>=2 && subDomain.characters.count<=6)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (accountName == "" || accountName.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: unWantedInUName)) != nil ||  domainName == "" || domainName.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: unWantedInDomain)) != nil || subDomain == "" || subDomain.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: unWantedInSub)) != nil ) {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: I will check it and then told you it's working or not.

Comment: sure I have tested in playground :)

Comment: @JeckyModi modi is this worked or not, if is there any problem then please let me know ??

Comment: Email without dot are perfectly valid like `me@localhost` or `whatever_is_your_name@com` see:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples